# Batch assigning a certain category to existing entries

Tags: categories

I have a few 1000 existing entries and just introduced a new Category type. And I would need to assign all existing entries, to a certain category.

I've been looking in the MySQL databases what exactly is going on, so I could reproduce it with a query directly in there, but can't seem to pinpoint exactly what I would need to update.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could build a plugin to grab all the entries and then assign that new category to it that way.

This bit of code is untested but this should do it, since this is a one off thing, you can get away with just doing it in chunks by setting the limit and offset, otherwise I'd recommend creating this as a Task:

```
// get all the entries
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = "news"; // just using news as an example, be sure to set the appropriate section handle
$criteria->limit = null;
// $criteria->offset = null; // you could use the limit and offset field to do this 200 at a time, to avoid it timing out on you
$criteria->status = null;
$entries = $criteria->find();

$categoryIds = array(222); // this would be the new category (its ID) that you want to assign to the entry, be sure to set the correct ID here

for($i=0; $i<count($entries); $i++)
{
    $entry = $entries[$i]; // for easier reference

    // lets get the existing categories that are assigned to this entry and add it to the new category ID you set a few lines above, if there are no existing categories for this, then you can remove this for loop entirely
    for($c=0; $c<count($entry->categoryFieldHandle); $c++)
    {
        $categoryIds[] = $entry->categoryFieldHandle[$c]->id; // be sure to replace categoryFieldHandle with the category field handle for the category field
    }

    // setting the categories to this field, be sure to replace categoryFieldHandle here too
    $entry->getContent()->setAttributes(array(
        'categoryFieldHandle' => $categoryIds,
    ));

    craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry); // save the entry
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found myself doing this exact thing. The trick is to use `saveRelations` to set the category.

In my example, my category id is `18840`, my field is `market`, and my section is `events`.

I created a throwaway action in my exiting `site` plugin:

```
public function actionSetmarket()
{
  $catIds = array(18840);
  $fieldModel = craft()->fields->getFieldByHandle('market');
  $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
  $criteria->section = 'events';
  $criteria->limit = null;
  foreach ($criteria as $entry) {
    craft()->relations->saveRelations($fieldModel, $entry, $catIds);
  }
}
```

Which can be run from `/actions/site/setmarket`